# Lambda and API gateway mapping

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I want to return a value from handler to API gateway response header.

Handler.js

```
module.exports.handler = function(event, context, cb) {
  const UpdateDate = new Date();  
  return cb(null, {
    body: {
      message: 'test'
    },
    header: {
      Last-Modified: UpdateDate
    }
  });
};
```

s-function.json in "endpoints"

```
"responses": {
    "400": {
      "statusCode": "400"
    },
    "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Cache-Control": "'public, max-age=86400'",
        "method.response.header.Last-Modified": "integration.response.body.header.Last-Modified"
      },
      "responseModels": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "Empty"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "$input.json('$.body')"
      }
    }
  }
```

This can work. But I want to know how to use "integration.response.header.Last-Modified". Is my handler callback formate wrong?

Edit:
s-function.json in "endpoints"

"integration.response.header.Last-Modified" This doesn't work.
I want to know specific handler return formate to pass data to "integration.response.header.Last-Modified".

```
"responses": {
    "400": {
      "statusCode": "400"
    },
    "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Cache-Control": "'public, max-age=86400'",
        "method.response.header.Last-Modified": "integration.response.header.Last-Modified"
      },
      "responseModels": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "Empty"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "$input.json('$.body')"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks correct on first glance but I don't understand your question. Are you saying this *doesn't* work? If not, what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I want to use "integration.response.header.Last-Modified" and I don't know lambda return formate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the output from your lambda function is returned in the response body, so you will need to map part of the response body to your API response header.

```
module.exports.handler = function(event, context, cb) {
  const UpdateDate = new Date();  
  return cb(null, {
      message: 'test',
      Last-Modified: UpdateDate
  });
};
```

will produce payload "{"message" : "test", "Last-Modified" : "..."}"

In this case you would use "integration.response.body.Last-Modified" as the mapping expression. As a side note, naming things "body" and "header" in your response body may make the mapping expressions confusing to read.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Thank you! This help me a lot.